# Why does aligning two flex children to the right fail, while aligning one works?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an unordered list with several items. Let's admit is necessary, for whatever reason, for the list to have it's `display` property set to `flex`.

If I align one item to the right by setting it's  `margin-left` to `auto`, that works (unsurprisingly):

```css
.flex-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-list li {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #069;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flex-list  .right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li class="right">5</li>
</ul>
```

If instead I want to align *two items* to the right, that does not work:

```css
.flex-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-list li {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #069;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flex-list  .right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="right">4</li>
  <li class="right">5</li>
</ul>
```

Why is that? How can I align the last two items to the right?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You are essentially asking that the flex parent container make an exception to it's `justification` property for two of it's children. If I'm wrong, that's awesome.

Comment: @disinfor I do not need `justify-content: space-between;`, I am willing to loose it.

Comment: The closest I got to a solution for you is dropping the `justify-content` from the parent, adding `position: relative` to the `li` and adding `left: 55%` to `.right` class. But this will break pretty quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just set a `margin-left: auto` on the fourth element, you should get the result you want.

```css
.flex-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-list li {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #069;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flex-list  .right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="right">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did set `margin-left: auto` on the fourth element. And that did **not** give me the desired result. Or are you saying "on the fourth element only"?

Comment: You need to set the `margin-left: auto` on the fourth element only. So you have to remove it from the fifth element for it to work as intended.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understood what you want then. Setting `margin-left: auto` on the 4th element will right align the 4th and 5th elements, and left align the first 3

Comment: The solution works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/mvadjr1L/12/ However, you would always have to split it at the 4th element. This wouldn't work for dynamic lists

Comment: @disinfor Dynamic in what way? As long as there's a single `.right` item, this will work.

Comment: @MrLister sorry, I should have been more clear. Talking about dynamically shifting. Like if the list was only three items long and the last had to be shifted.